# applying JSP/JSTL's <c:url> to a path inside a servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets, spring-mvc, spring-security, jstl

In our JSP pages, we use  extensively.  Works great, rewrites the URL to deal with sessionids, contexts, etc.  But now we need to do some of this work inside a class that takes an HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse as part of the Spring Security specification.

How do I apply a  type transformation to a path in a servlet?  I guess I could reconstruct the URL with the scheme, host, port, context, path and query parameters (am I missing anything?).  But I'd love a standard way to do this so I know it's being done properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`HttpServletResponse#encodeURL()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#encodeURL%28java.lang.String%29) and [`HttpServletResponse#encodeRedirectURL()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#encodeRedirectURL%28java.lang.String%29) deals with sessionids. The context can be obtained by [`HttpServletRequest#getContextPath()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getContextPath%28%29).

Comment: Thanks BalusC.  I was aware of the response and request methods to reconstruct the URL, I was just hoping there was a simple standard way like JSTL's <c:url value="/path"/>.  This is the route I ended up using though.